# WCF Website Service on Azure VM - No endpoint listening issue

Tags: wcf, azure

I need help setting up my Azure virtual machine to allow connection to my WCF website service. Please, I am just missing something simple relative to Azure.

I get this error:

**"There was no endpoint listening at http://mydomainname.com/registrations.svc that could accept the message"**

**I have set up the HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and other endpoints for my VM.**

I have searched the web and this site for hours and still no answer - like lots of other folks it seems.

Details:

I have a website on an Azure Virtual Machine (Server 2008). The website is a copy of our production website hosted on our local server. The website has a WCF service used by a windows desktop client. Everything woks on our local server.
Everything on the Azure server works except access to the service. **My registered domain name points to the Azure Server public IP address so accessing website hosted on the Azure machine works.**
Example:  http://www.mydomainname.com brings up my ASP.NET website. It works as expected including the https binding.

**The service seems to be visible to the outside world. 
Example  http://www.mydomainname.com/Registrations.svc?wsdl  brings up the details of the service.**

Also, if I put a copy of the client code on the VM and a local host version of the website on the VM (using VS Express for web debug) and change the url in my client to point to the local host version of the service - that all works

I have not changed any firewall settings as of yet because I did not need to do so in our onsite server (or even on an ISP webserver).

Here is the service info:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="RegistrationsService" behaviorConfiguration="RegistrationsServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IRegistrations"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RegistrationsServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone tell me what I may be missing.

1. Do I need to set up another endpoint for my VM in Azure Portal so WCF will work: Name=AnyName? Protocol= "TCP;  public port = ?  Private Port= ?
2. After the above, what ports do I enable in server firewall (the public port or the private port)
3. Anything else different between an Azure Virtual Machine and other Virtual machines (like our onsite servers or ISP web servers)
4. Are there any settings I may have missed in IIS or other places. I have everything set just like in our local server where the website and services work.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Dennis